# how to keep relationship between feature classes after intersection one of feature classes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, relationship-class

I have geodatabase with 3 feature classes. one of them is circuit polyline feature class and two polygon feature class. substation and division

in geodatabase there is relationship between circuit and substation. I am going to intersect between division and substation. the result of relation  will be feature class with all substation and in attribute table all data about substations and division are available. but my problem is that there isnt the relation between circuit and substation in result feature class from intersect? 
how can I make intersect feature class between sub and div that relation between substation and other classes maintain?